# Spam Query in magento 1.9.0

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting more than 50 spam query form failing on my Magento 1.9.0, website https://www.shubhgems.in, I have tried the robots.txt method and blocked 360 Spider User-agent: 360Spider Disallow: /

But it didn't help me to stop spam queries, Please guide me how I can stop spam queries

Comment: You can use this extention for stop spam query: https://magecomp.com/magento-google-recaptcha.html